# Re enabling disable full html in Drupal 7

Tags: php, filter, drupal-7, text-formatting

Clicking too quickly I mistakenly disabled the text format "Full HTML" in drupal 7. I read in the core module filters that there is no way to re enable this from the core. Is there any way I can get this text format back or something that mirrors its permissions? Thank you for helping a newbie.

Answer (score 8):

This is a known bug: https://www.drupal.org/node/2502637

What you can do, carefully, is go into your Drupal database, to the table `filter_format` and change the `status` to 1

```
UPDATE  drupal.filter_format SET  status =  '1' WHERE  filter_format.format =  'full_html';
```

Comment: Here it comes as a handy drush command `drush sql-query "UPDATE filter_format SET status = '1' WHERE filter_format.format = 'full_html'"`.

Answer (score 1):

"Full-HTML" format:
This link provides instructions to do so:
http://drupal.org/node/778976

Comment: Drupal does not allow to use "full_html" as machine name of the new filter, as its there already in the database. So its not possible to create new filter with name "Full-HTML".